# runas the Microsoft Store version of WhatsApp

Tags: windows-11, runas, whatsapp, microsoft-store

I'm trying to run two instances of WhatsApp for two different accounts. Previously, when WhatsApp was a desktop application it was possible to run it as a different user with `runas`, but the desktop version is no longer updated.

I tried the same approach with the Microsoft Store version, installed the app for both Windows users. But the executable terminates instantly with no error message. I tried to launch the app shortcut copied from `shell:AppsFolder` and the `.exe` file directly.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible

Comment: Can't you use a browser, by using two different browsers or two browser profiles?

Comment: @harrymc 
I checked. The web version doesn't support voice calls

Comment: [WhatsApp beta on Windows now supports audio and video calls with up to 32 people](https://mspoweruser.com/whatsapp-beta-on-windows-now-supports-audio-and-video-calls-with-up-to-32-peo). Is this pertinent?

Answer (score 0):

old whatsapp i'm start with:

```
runas /user:mobileapp24 /savecred "C:\Program Files\WhatsApp\WhatsApp.exe"
```

Now whatsapp from Windows store, i can't start:

```
runas /user:mobileapp24 /savecred "powershell.exe -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs shell:appsFolder\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm!App"


powershell.exe -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs "shell:appsFolder\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm!App"


runas /user:mobileapp24 /savecred "powershell.exe    Start-Process shell:appsFolder\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm!App -verb runas
```

Not work

Use link for whatsapp and Run as deferent user(Shift+RightClick)
Not work - start myself user

Any ideas?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).